# Why google signin not working when i use native app package name and keystore files to flutter android app?

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

I have native android app which has google signin feature..i am able to login into google

I have implmented the flutter application for android with same application ID(i.e same as native android app in first point)

I am getting the below error while signin with flutter app E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Could you please provide solution to get out of this issue

Note: i used same keystore files in native and flutter app

Answer (score 0):

You should create "key.properties" file in your_project/android/(key.properties will be here) then write inside these;

```
storePassword=yourPassword
keyPassword=yourPassword
keyAlias=key
storeFile=\\key.jks
```

(Note: the key.jks is in "your_project/android/app/... or /your_project/... I put it two different place and I don't know which one is working :D )

Then it may be work. If you can't, you can send e-mail to Google to change your keystore of your app in the store.